# Live create and delete flightPath

Tags: google-maps

I create flightPath, but I can't use this. I write function console '123', but don't it... How I can to use flightPath?

```js
const mapOptions = {
    //mapOption
};
const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

let flightPath = {};

function createPoint(e) {
  //createPoint
}

function createLineBetweenPoints() {
  const flightPathOptions = {
    //option
    map: map
  };
  flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline(flightPathOptions);
}

function createRoutes(e) {
  createPoint(e);
  createLineBetweenPoints(e);
}

map.addListener('click', createRoutes);

google.maps.event.addListener(flightPath, 'click', function() {
    console.log(123);// don't work
});
```

Comment: The `createPoint` function posted doesn't do anything (so there is no way with the posted code to create a polyline.  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to add a google maps event listener to an empty object `{}`, that doesn't work.  You need to add it to the `google.maps.Polyline` once it exists.

```
function createLineBetweenPoints() {
  const flightPathOptions = {
    //option
    map: map,
  };
  flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline(flightPathOptions);
  google.maps.event.addListener(flightPath, 'click', function() {
    console.log(123);
  });
}
```